# Transform soapui xml test result into xls/csv format?

Tags: soapui, transformation

Below is the command to run the Soap UI project.

Once the execution is complete, I will be getting results in an xml file which I would like to transform it into `xls/csv` format.

```
/home/user/SmartBear/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/testrunner.sh -e$endpoint -rjf $resultfile $projectnew
```

Comment: Use style sheet to transform.

Comment: The question as it sands does not have much to do with SoapUI.
Converting XML to various other formats is a broader topic and is covered quite a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `testrunner.sh -FXLS ...`.

See [official documentation](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html) for other supported formats.

Comment: `-F` is not available for Open Source edition and applicable for ReadyAPI, and question seems to be related to SoapUI OS.